# jQuery on click event partially working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

```
var sideBarAndWrapper = $("#Sidebar,#Wrapper");

$("#SidebarToggle").on("click", function ()
{
    sideBarAndWrapper.toggleClass("hide-sidebar");

    if (sideBarAndWrapper.hasClass("hide-sidebar")) $(this).text("Show Sidebar");
    else $(this).text("Hide Sidebar");     
});
```

So the sideBarAndWrapper var toggles the class when clicking on "SidebarToggle", yet it doesn't do anything on the if-else statement.

I tried setting an alarm instead of the changing text instruction still nothing.
I also tried setting an alarm outside the if-else statement to see if it works on "SidebarToggle" click and nothing happens.

Click event doesn't do anything more than creating/removing the class.

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve] with HTML and CSS. You likely cannot use the collection to ask if they haveClass. Use one of them or set a data attribute on the SidebarToggle

Comment: Can you please edit a snippet using the `<>` snippet editor and show something we can test?

Answer (score 1):

`sideBarAndWrapper` Is a collection. You can set both but ***PERHAPS*** not interrogate using hasClass - in v3.1.1 you can

Try this more elegant version

```
var $sideBarAndWrapper = $("#Sidebar,#Wrapper");

$("#SidebarToggle").on("click", function () {
  var tgl = $(this).data("tgl") || false; // or true depending on state
  $sideBarAndWrapper.toggleClass("hide-sidebar",tgl);
  $(this).text(tgl?"Show Sidebar":"Hide Sidebar");
  $(this).data("tgl",!tgl);     
});
```

Comment: Tried this aswell, but it doesn't work. As I said it seems like it is a problem on the click event because anything aside from the class toggling doesn't work in it.

Comment: Shockingly, you can. [Example pen here](http://codepen.io/mattbontrager/pen/zZeExB?editors=1010). I totally didn't think you could either.

Comment: @Lucanian if the above does not work, then there is another issue - .on or .click should work the same

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Updating my answer with [working code/full example](http://codepen.io/mattbontrager/pen/zZeExB?editors=1010):

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
<div id="wrapper">wrapper</div>

<button>click</button>

<p id="fill-me"></p>
```

jQuery

```
var $sideBarAndWrapper = $("#sidebar,#wrapper");

$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  $sideBarAndWrapper.toggleClass('hide-sidebar');

  if ($sideBarAndWrapper.hasClass('hide-sidebar')) {
    $('#fill-me').empty().text('show sidebar');
  } else {
    $('#fill-me').empty().text('hide sidebar');
  }
});
```

Although I agree with mplungjan, and you should be selecting your elements in a more effective way, it works if you write your if/else statement correctly.

```
if (sideBarAndWrapper.hasClass("hide-sidebar")) {
    $(this).text("Show Sidebar");
} else {
    $(this).text("Hide Sidebar");
}
```

Here is an [excellent place to start](http://jqfundamentals.com) on the basics, written and published by [Rebecca Murphey](https://rmurphey.com)

Comment: I am pretty sure that for 1 instruction the if/else statement works without {}. Still I tried and it doesn't work :(

Comment: What is the difference between what OP wrote and yours other than the {} - of course if it works it works and then the original issue is not what OP thought it was. Perhaps a jQuery version issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a glitch with the syntax for

```
$("#SidebarToggle").on("click",function(){}).
```

Replacing it with
 `$("#SidebarToggle").click(function(){})` did the trick and now it's working perfectly.